# BATCH: Subtract the system date with one day before

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible that I set a parameter one day before today?

So I read out the system time:

```
 set ARCHIV=%DATE:~0,2%%DATE:~2,2%%DATE:~4,6%
```

And now the output is 12.06.2014 (DD.MM.YYYY)

And I want that the output is 11.06.2014

I really don't know if it's possible to subtract the output date with one day.
I had found only commands to subtract it with another date.

Regards

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980034/subtract-days-in-batch-file?rq=1

Comment: Another option [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23048600/2861476)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get and display yesterday date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954359/how-to-get-and-display-yesterday-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code for delete the file with name of one day less than current date (format YYYYMMDD)

```
 @echo off
 setlocal

 Call :GetDateTime Year Month Day
 set A=%Year%%Month%%Day%

 Call :SubtractDate %Year% %Month% %Day% -1 Ret

 set b=%Ret%
 @echo %b%
 @echo ###start Coping
 :: variables
 Set source=F:\
 Set destination=F:\
 set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
 echo %drive%
 echo %destination%
 echo ### Backing up My folder...
 %backupcmd% "%source%" "%destination%\%b%"

 :SubtractDate Year Month Day <+/-Days> Ret
 ::Adapted from DosTips Functions::
 setlocal & set a=%4
 set "yy=%~1"&set "mm=%~2"&set "dd=%~3"
 set /a "yy=10000%yy% %%10000,mm=100%mm% %% 100,dd=100%dd% %% 100"
 if %yy% LSS 100 set /a yy+=2000 &rem Adds 2000 to two digit years
 set /a JD=dd-32075+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4
 if %a:~0,1% equ + (set /a JD=%JD%+%a:~1%) else set /a JD=%JD%-%a:~1%
 set /a L= %JD%+68569,     N= 4*L/146097, L= L-(146097*N+3)/4, I= 4000*(L+1)/1461001
 set /a L= L-1461*I/4+31, J= 80*L/2447,  K= L-2447*J/80,      L= J/11
 set /a J= J+2-12*L,      I= 100*(N-49)+I+L
 set /a YYYY= I, MM=100+J, DD=100+K
 set MM=%MM:~-2% & set DD=%DD:~-2%
 set ret=%YYYY: =%%MM: =%%DD: =%
 endlocal & set %~5=%ret%
 exit /b

 :GetDateTime Year Month Day Hour Minute Second
 @echo off & setlocal
 for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
 set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
 set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
 ( ENDLOCAL
    IF "%~1" NEQ "" set "%~1=%YYYY%" 
    IF "%~2" NEQ "" set "%~2=%MM%" 
    IF "%~3" NEQ "" set "%~3=%DD%"
    IF "%~4" NEQ "" set "%~4=%HH%" 
    IF "%~5" NEQ "" set "%~5=%Min%"
    IF "%~6" NEQ "" set "%~6=%Sec%"
 )
 exit /b
```

Comment: thanks, but i can't find the variable for the date yesterday for example i want to create a folder from the date yesterday or want to use xcopy :D 
did you know what i mean ?
Sorry i am a beginner in batch...

Comment: Set source and destination for the file need to Xcopy